# Compaq with OS nightmare!

Tags: linux, windows, drivers

I have a crazy situation with a Compaq Presario M2010us.

Basically the computer had XP Home on it. It was malfunctioning and running really slow! So I threw in a XP media edition to a dead Inspiron and used to product key to register(I know, I know: stupid, I was desperate at the time)

To remedy this I tried to put Ubuntu 10.10 on it due to the fact that I was having alot of issues downloading drivers from hp's website. The biggest obstacle was that the CD driver didn't work. So it wouldn't read the Linux disk.

So: further down the rabbit hole we go... I used Magic ISO to mount Linux inside Windows, hoping that I would be prompted to reformat and eventually rid computer of windows. no such luck. The whole thing is so screwy I just want to wipe it all out. I have a bootleg Compaq OS disk. It won't read that either.

I just tried to reformat from the command prompt in windows but it denied me because Linux is in use.

I was think of using dban but that leads me back to the CD driver issue. Magic ISO won't mount it for me either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Buy a new CD drive

Comment: Something like Magic ISO or DAEMONTools should have no problem mounting an image, regardless of issues with your existing CD-ROM device or drivers.  Still, I would strongly recommend against using such tools as a replacement for a real CD-ROM drive during an OS installation.

Comment: Are you using the paid version of Magic ISO?  According to Wikipedia, the free version is limited to handling images of 300 MB or less.  https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Magic_iso

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to install from an USB stick [like explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) ?